# how to pass parameter to SQL stored procedure from crystal report?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have created a SQL server stored procedure and it is attached into the crystal report.
Can you please guide me how I can use this stored procedrue into a formula field.
I drag and drop it and it generated code snip like below:

```
{spTest;1.Expr1000}
```

But this stored procedure also take 2 parameter (Para1 and Para2).

Can you please guide how to pass these parameters.

Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

When creating your stored procedure you will use Para1 and Para2 in your Create Stored Procedure or Alter Stored Procedure statement (assuming a data type of datetime):

```
create Procedure ProcedureName @Para1 datetime, @Para2 datetime as
```

Try adding the parameter declarations in your Stored Procedure, and once done, go to Database/Verify Database in CR to refresh your connection.  Crystal should create the parameters for you.